# xamarin android get files as list from web directory

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

How to get all files from web directory as list in ListView?

I tried this

```
button4.Click += async delegate
{
    var list = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

    var client = new HttpClient();
    var json = await client.GetStringAsync("http://myurl.com/uploads/");


    var itemsfile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(json);

    list.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, itemsfile);
};
```

Comment: print out the value of `itemsfile`... Is there data in it?

Comment: no. Unhandled Exception:

System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Comment: Please , any idea

Comment: You shouldn't use `client.GetStringAsync("http://myurl.com/uploads/")`, it will return you the web page's html code, so the `json` is not Json format. You need to get a interface from your server. Are you testing web crawler in Xamarin.Android?

Comment: welcome Joe, Could you give me the code please ? I tried a lot of times and I did not got it. thanks

Comment: I am waiting any idea ... help me please I did not got it until now.

Comment: Please @me, so I can get the message on time. I mean  `client.GetStringAsync("http://myurl.com/uploads/")` this can't get what you want, you need get a interface which you can use in `Xamarin.Android` to get the Json about list of directory from back-end. And ask again, Are you testing web crawler in Xamarin.Android?  By ` I tried a lot of times and I did not got it. ` What have you tried?

Comment: You can print `json` in your code, and you will see it is not Json format, is it right? It just html string, that is why you can't get files. And another question, do you have back-end? Does this web site belong to you?

Comment: hello Joe, do you have idea or code to do that ? Thanks